# Invertibility of a monotone matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question regarding monotone matrix. How to prove that monotone matrix is invertible?

Comment: What do you mean by monotone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given that $Ax\ge 0$ implies $x\ge 0$. Assume there is $x\ne 0$ with $Ax=0$. Then atleast one of $x$ and $-x$ fails to be $\ge0$.

Comment: Can you clarify this proof? Why does this mean that x or -x is greater or equal to 0?